# Выбор даты в React Native

Tags: reactjs, ios, дата, native

Делаю приложение на React Native, для доставки пиццы. И в форме оформления заказа хочу сделать выбор времени доставки. Подскажите, как сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочется именно как в Календаре iOS.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]